# How to call solidity function which has array of address as an argument using web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

Say i have a contract as follows:

```
contract A {
  function passAddress(address[] _addr) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

How do i call this function in my frontend application using web3. 
I tried using javascript array but it throws revert exception.

Any ideas ?

Comment: A JavaScript array is the right way to do this via web3.js. Can you share your code? (Also share the rest of the contract code so we can guess at where the `revert` was.)

Answer (score 3):

You are only able to pass datatypes which the contract recognises, so passing a javascript array is not an option.

If you have an array of all your addresses, you could try joining them using javascript, and passing the resulting string using web3.
ie,

if you have

```
array = [0x0,0x0,0x0];
```

and you made that

```
string = '["0x0","0x0","0x0"]'
```

and pass that string as the "array" then that could do the trick

Comment: This is incorrect for web3.js. A JavaScript array is the right way to pass an array to a smart contract.

Comment: I can pass string and uint arrays but the problem is with address[]

Comment: could you share the javascript code you used to call the function with web3?

Comment: what about web3.py

Comment: Thanks, this is what made it work when interacting with the contract manually in web or remix.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass array as follows :-

```
  var contractAbi = eth.contract(AbiOfContract);
  var myContract = contractAbi.at(contractAddress);
  var getData = myContract.passAddress.getData([address1,address2,address3]);
  // var getData = myContract.passAddress.getData(["0x0","0x0","0x0"]);
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:Contractaddress, from:Accountaddress, data: getData});
```

Comment: I get TypeError: mycontract.passAddress.getData is not a function

Comment: @Are you using any framework?

Comment: myContract.methods.passAddress(params).encodeABI();

Answer (score 0):

Adoption is my smart contract. I using this way to call function which array of address as an argument.

```
App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  adoptionInstance = instance;
  return adoptionInstance.passAddress("address1, address2,...");
}).then(function(adopters) {
  console.log("function success");
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log("function error" + err.message);
});
```